# Error in symbols font on tmux statusbar

Tags: tmux, rxvt

Look at my Tmux status bar:

[image]

I down't see symbols. How I can fix this?

My config files is these:

**.Xresurces**

```
#define S_base03        #002b36
#define S_base02        #073642
#define S_base01        #586e75
#define S_base00        #657b83
#define S_base0         #839496
#define S_base1         #93a1a1
#define S_base2         #eee8d5
#define S_base3         #fdf6e3
#define S_yellow        #b58900
#define S_orange        #cb4b16
#define S_red           #dc322f
#define S_magenta       #d33682
#define S_violet        #6c71c4
#define S_blue          #268bd2
#define S_cyan          #2aa198
#define S_green         #859900

URxvt*background:            S_base03
URxvt*foreground:            S_base0
URxvt*fading:                40
URxvt*fadeColor:             S_base03
URxvt*cursorColor:           S_base1
URxvt*pointerColorBackground:S_base01
URxvt*pointerColorForeground:S_base1

!!  black dark/light
URxvt*color0:                S_base02
URxvt*color8:                S_base03

!!  red dark/light
URxvt*color1:                S_red
URxvt*color9:                S_orange

!!  green dark/light
URxvt*color2:                S_green
URxvt*color10:               S_base01

!!  yellow dark/light
URxvt*color3:                S_yellow
URxvt*color11:               S_base00

!!  blue dark/light
URxvt*color4:                S_blue
URxvt*color12:               S_base0

!!  magenta dark/light
URxvt*color5:                S_magenta
URxvt*color13:               S_violet

!!  cyan dark/light
URxvt*color6:                S_cyan
URxvt*color14:               S_base1

!!  white dark/light
URxvt*color7:                S_base2
URxvt*color15:               S_base3


URxvt*font: xft:Inconsolata for Powerline:size=12,xft:PowerlineSymbols:pixelsize=12:antialias=true

URxvt*scrollBar: False
URxvt*scrollTtyOutput: False
URxvt*scrollTtyKeypress: True
URxvt*secondaryScroll: True
URxvt*saveLines: 8000
URxvt*letterSpace: 0
URxvt*cursorBlink: True
URxvt*cursorUnderline: True

URxvt*modifier: alt

URxvt.perl-ext-common : default,matcher,keyboard-select,url-select,clipboard

URxvt.tabbed.tabbar-fg: 5
URxvt.tabbed.tabbar-bg: 0
URxvt.tabbed.tab-fg: 14
URxvt.tabbed.tab-bg: 0

URxvt.keysym.M-Escape: perl:keyboard-select:activate
URxvt.keysym.M-s: perl:keyboard-select:search

URxvt.keysym.M-u: perl:url-select:select_next
URxvt.url-select.autocopy: True
URvxt.url-select.button: 2
URxvt.url-select.launcher: firefox
URxvt.url-select.underline: True

URxvt.keysym.M-c: perl:clipboard:copy
URxvt.keysym.M-v: perl:clipboard:paste
URxvt.keysym.M-C-v: perl:clipboard:paste_escaped
```

And **.tmux.conf**:

```
# use UTF8
set -g utf8
set-window-option -g utf8 on
set -g status on
set -g status-utf8 on

# make tmux display things in 256 colors
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# set scrollback history to 10000 (10k)
set -g history-limit 10000

# set Ctrl-a as the default prefix key combination
# and unbind C-b to free it up
set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b

# use send-prefix to pass C-a through to application
bind C-a send-prefix

# shorten command delay
set -sg escape-time 1

# set window and pane index to 1 (0 by default)
set-option -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1

# reload ~/.tmux.conf using PREFIX r
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"

# use PREFIX | to split window horizontally and PREFIX - to split vertically
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v

# Make the current window the first window
bind T swap-window -t 1

# map Vi movement keys as pane movement keys
bind -n S-down new-window

bind -n C-right select-pane -R
bind -n C-left select-pane -L
bind -n C-up select-pane -U
bind -n C-down select-pane -D

bind -n S-right next
bind -n S-left prev


bind l select-pane -R

# and use C-h and C-l to cycle thru panes
bind -r C-h select-window -t :-
bind -r C-l select-window -t :+

# resize panes using PREFIX H, J, K, L
bind H resize-pane -L 10
bind J resize-pane -D 10
bind K resize-pane -U 10
bind L resize-pane -R 10

# C-i for even-vertical arrangement and C-o to zoom current pane
bind-key C-i select-layout even-vertical
bind-key C-v select-layout even-horizontal
#bind-key C-o resize-pane -y 1000

# Sync panes
bind C-s set-window-option synchronize-panes

# explicitly disable mouse control
setw -g mode-mouse off
set -g mouse-select-pane off
set -g mouse-resize-pane off
set -g mouse-select-window off

# ---------------------
# Copy & Paste
# ---------------------
# provide access to the clipboard for pbpaste, pbcopy
#set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"
set-window-option -g automatic-rename on

# use vim keybindings in copy mode
setw -g mode-keys vi

bind y run 'tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy '
bind C-y run 'tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy '

# -----------------------
# Multistart panes
# ----------------------
bind-key P run-shell 'tmux-multistart as'
bind-key A run-shell 'tmux-multistart alpha'
bind-key B run-shell 'tmux-multistart beta'
bind-key W run-shell 'tmux-multistart web'
bind-key D run-shell 'tmux-multistart dev'
bind-key T run-shell 'tmux-multistart txhub'

bind-key C command-prompt -p "machine(s)/group: " "run-shell 'tmux-multistart %1'"

# ----------------------
# set some pretty colors
# ----------------------
# set pane colors - hilight the active pane
set-option -g pane-border-fg colour235 #base02
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg colour240 #base01

# colorize messages in the command line
set-option -g message-bg black #base02
set-option -g message-fg brightred #orange

# ----------------------
# Status Bar
# -----------------------

# visual notification of activity in other windows
setw -g monitor-activity on
set -g visual-activity on

# set color for status bar
set-option -g status-bg colour236 #base02
set-option -g status-fg yellow #yellow
set-option -g status-attr dim 

# set window list colors - red for active and cyan for inactive
set-window-option -g window-status-fg brightblue #base0
set-window-option -g window-status-bg colour236 
set-window-option -g window-status-attr dim

set-window-option -g window-status-current-fg brightred #orange
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg colour236 
set-window-option -g window-status-current-attr bright

# show host name and IP address on left side of status bar
set -g status-left-length 85 

set -g status-right-length 60

set -g status-right '#[fg=colour16,bg=colour254,bold] #S #[fg=colour254,bg=colour234,nobold]'
set -g status-left '#(eval tmux-airline `tmux display -p "#{client_width}"`)'

set -g window-status-format "#[fg=colour244,bg=colour234]#I #[fg=colour240] #[default]#W "
set -g window-status-current-format "#[fg=colour234,bg=colour31]#[fg=colour117,bg=colour31] #I  #[fg=colour231,bold]#W #[fg=colour31,bg=colour234,nobold]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

I had another error message with sublime about set locate for non-ascii characters in arch.

So arch's wiki help to set locale setting with this command:

```
$ locale > /etc/locale.conf
```

After i3 restart everythings is OK